# Trying to add XSRF validation to contact form

Tags: module, overrides, magento-1, controllers

I am trying to block a recent "Contact Us" form spammer.  I figured the best way to do this is by adding a form key and validating it in the controller.

This works when I modify core files, which is obviously not what the end solution should be,

I have read several questions and tutorials on overriding a controller, and I have tried them with no luck, the core controller always gets used, and the validation never happens.  What am I doing wrong? (note: I have not created a module in Magento as of yet, this is my first)

Here's what I have:

New file: `app/code/local/ACS/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`

This is a copy of the core file `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` with the addition of

```
if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
    $error = true;
}
```

in the `try` block of the `postAction()` function.

2nd New File:  `app/code/local/ACS/Contacts/etc/config.xml`

Which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <acs_contacts>
      <vesion>0.1.0</version>
    </acs_contacts>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <contacts>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <contacts before="Mage_Contacts">ACS_Contacts</contacts>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </contacts>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

And finally, last new file `app/etc/modules/ACS_Contacts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ACS_Contacts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
   </ACS_Contacts>
 </modules>
</config>
```

And of course I have added the form_key to `app/design/frontend/theme/template/contacts/form.phtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix your `app/code/local/ACS/Contacts/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ACS_Contacts>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ACS_Contacts>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <contacts>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <ACS_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">ACS_Contacts</ACS_Contacts>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </contacts>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Then your `app/etc/modules/ACS_Contacts.xml` needs a little update:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ACS_Contacts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
          <Mage_Contacts/>
      </depends>
   </ACS_Contacts>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Finally, don't simply copy `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` into `app/code/local/ACS/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`, make your new controller extend the original controller and just create your own `postAction` method:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php';

class ACS_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
         // Here you can copy the original method and modify it to fit your needs
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have made the changes you suggested, "ACS_Contacts" is now the same case everywhere and my controller extends the core and only defines the postAction function including the key validation.  Unfortunately, it still appears to be using the unmodified controller.

Comment: @DavidWilkins did you copy my entire definition of the `config.xml` ? Because you also had a typo `vesion` instead of `version` .

Comment: Ah!  I totally missed the typo in "version".  When I corrected that, I (correctly) got an internal server error, because I also missed the `include_once` in the controller.  After correcting those, it works!  THANKS!~

Comment: @DavidWilkins glad you figured it out =D

Answer (score 2):

In config.xml file

```
<acs_contacts>
      <vesion>0.1.0</version>
</acs_contacts>
```

changed to:

```
<ACS_Contacts>
      <vesion>0.1.0</version>
</ACS_Contacts>
```